# Setting up Latex Workshop to work with flatpak version of VS Code (Debian)

Tags: ubuntu, debian, vscode, latex-workshop

My question concerns a specific VS Code setup I chose within my Debian 12 distro -- I basically went with the flatpak route in order to avoid installing VS Code from a proprietary/unofficial package repository (for now).

I guess it shouldn't have come as a surprise that upon installing the LaTeX Workshop extension within the `com.visualstudio.code` flatpak app, all the tools and recipes seem to be broken (for instance, the `latexmk` build command throws the `Recipe terminated with fatal error: spawn latexmk ENOENT` error).

Curiously, however, I can build just fine from the integrated terminal, spawned using the following `settings.json` parameters (as per the [official documentation](https://github.com/flathub/com.visualstudio.code#use-host-shell-in-the-integrated-terminal)).

```
  "host-bash": {
    "path": "/app/bin/host-spawn",
    "args": ["bash"],
    "icon": "terminal-bash",
    "overrideName": true
  }
```

Since I am able to compile LaTeX documents from within VS Code's integrated terminal, I figure there must be a way to get the tools and recipes for the extension configured properly, but have run into a brick wall. I have tried fiddling with the SHELL and PATH environment variables, etc., but no luck so far. I did eventually set up and got an external build command working by pointing it to a shell script I wrote, but unfortunately this disables all the other built-in build tools and recipes, so it may not be a viable long-term solution:

```
"latex-workshop.latex.external.build.command": "~/code/scripts/latex_workshop/latexmk.sh",
"latex-workshop.latex.external.build.args": [
  "%OUTDIR%",
  "%DOC%"
],
```

Before I give up and install VS Code via the `apt install` route, I wanted to check if anyone has successfully configured the LaTeX Workshop extension within the `com.visualstudio.code` flatpak app on a Debian based distro, and if so, I would very much appreciate some tips on how to get this setup to work.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: I have found a workaround which can be employed within the com.visualstudio.code flatpak, but there may be a better solution than the one I'm posting here.

For example, the `latexmk` tool definition could be modified as follows.
     {
        "name": "latexmk",
        "command": "/app/bin/host-spawn",
        "args": [
          "bash",
          "-c",
          "latexmk",
          "-synctex=1",
          "-interaction=nonstopmode",
          "-file-line-error",
          "-pdf",
          "-outdir=%OUTDIR%",
          "%DOC%"
        ],
        "env": {}
      },

Answer (score 2):

I'm reposting my workaround implemented within `settings.json` for clarity, in case someone else needs help resolving this, or a similar problem.

I guess this solves my issue for now, but would be interested to know if there's a more elegant way to spawn a host terminal session and then launch a LaTeX Workshop tool or recipe in there.

```
  {
    "name": "latexmk",
    "command": "/app/bin/host-spawn",
    "args": [
      "bash",
      "-c",
      "latexmk -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode -file-line-error -pdf -outdir=%OUTDIR% %DOC%"
    ],
    "env": {}
  }
```

Comment: UPDATE (2024-03-16): I recently realised Synctex files weren't being generated by the original recipe I'd posted. I actually had to collapse the entire `latexmk` command into a one-liner punctuated by spaces to get it to work.

I have updated my post to reflect this finding.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get LaTeX to work on Fedora Silverblue (VSCode Flatpak + toolbox)
Config:

```
"latex-workshop.latex.tools": [
    {
        "name": "latexmk",
        "command": "host-spawn",
        "args": [
            "toolbox",
            "run",
            "--container",
            "LaTeX",
            "latexmk",
            "-synctex=1",
            "-interaction=nonstopmode",
            "-file-line-error",
            "-pdf",
            "-outdir=%OUTDIR%",
            "%DOC%"
        ],
        "env": {}
    },
],

"latex-workshop.linting.chktex.enabled": true,
"latex-workshop.linting.chktex.exec.path": "host-spawn",
"latex-workshop.linting.chktex.exec.args": [
    "toolbox",
    "run",
    "--container",
    "LaTeX",
    "chktex",
    "-wall",
    "-n22",
    "-n30",
    "-e16",
    "-q"
]
```

Answer (score 1):

My `settings.json` for vscode code remote-ssh + latex-studio + fedora silverblue + toolbox, inspired by @lofilbzik

```
{
    "latex-workshop.hover.preview.cursor.enabled": true,
    "latex-workshop.latex.tools": [
        {
            "name": "latexmk",
            "command": "toolbox",
            "args": [
                "run",
                "--container",
                "texlive",
                "latexmk",
                "-synctex=1",
                "-interaction=nonstopmode",
                "-file-line-error",
                "-pdf",
                "-outdir=%OUTDIR%",
                "%DOC%"
            ],
            "env": {}
        },
    ],
    "latex-workshop.linting.chktex.enabled": true,
    "latex-workshop.linting.chktex.exec.path": "toolbox",
    "latex-workshop.linting.chktex.exec.args": [
        "run",
        "--container",
        "texlive",
        "chktex",
        "-wall",
        "-n22",
        "-n30",
        "-e16",
        "-q",
        "-I"
    ],
    "latex-workshop.latexindent.path": "toolbox",
    "latex-workshop.latexindent.args": [
        "run",
        "--container",
        "texlive",
        "latexindent",
        "-m",
        "-l", "%DIR%/latexindent.yaml",
        "-c",
        "%DIR%/",
        "%TMPFILE%",
    ],
}
```